# Numpy repeat array along new axis

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

What’s the best/most performant way?

with x being the array and n being the number of times i want it repeated:

```
np.repeat(x[None,...], n, axis=0)
```

or

```
ones = [1] * len(x.shape)
np.tile(x, tuple(n, *ones))
```

note that for a known array size, the latter becomes simple:

```
np.tile(x, (n, 1, 1))  # x is 2D
```

Comment: Have you tried... timing it?

Comment: More often than not, you'd want to apply this operation to the *last* axis, or better, depending on how you later use it, you can take advantage of numpy's broadcasting and avoid the repeatition altogether (which would surely be faster). If you give the bigger picture, we might be able to point out how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the code for `np.tile` is:

```
for i, nrep in enumerate(tup):
    if nrep!=1:
        c = c.reshape(-1, n).repeat(nrep, 0)
```

In other words, it does `repeat` on each of the axis with more than 1 repeat.  It is, effect, a generalization of `repeat` to multiple axes.

So I'd expect timings to be similar, though plain `repeat` will have less Python overhead.  `repeat` is compiled.  (a few simple tests confirm this - `repeat` is 2x faster for small arrays, slightly faster for large ones).

p.s. The `x[None,...]` step is virtually costless.  And due to broadcasting it might be all you need.

---

p.s.s.  There is an even faster way of doing this repeat, using `np.lib.index_tricks.as_strided`.  For a `(20,50)` shaped `x`,

```
as_strided(x,shape=(n,20,50),strides=(0,200,4))
```

`np.broadcast_arrays` also uses `as_strided`.  So this produces the same thing:

```
np.broadcast_arrays(np.ones((n,1,1)),x)[1]
```

But to be honest, this is just an elaboration on broadcasting, not a true repeat.  The data hasn't been replicated.  The same values are just used `n` times.

Broadcasting can be used to populate the full array, but the timings are the same as for `repeat`.  That may be what `repeat` is doing under the hood.

```
z = np.empty((300,20,50),dtype=int)
z[:] = x[None,...]
```

Comment: `index_tricks` is a cute name for a module. thanks! numpy is really awesome once you fully got into its mental model, sadly i’m not there yet.